# Combine two mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

This is the situation..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

$name = $row['name'];
$class = $row['class'];
$result = $row['phone'];

$data .= '<td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$class.'</td><td>'.$result.'</td>';
}



echo "<table><tr>'.$data.'</tr><table>"
```

`$name` and `$class` will occur once but `$result` will occur more than once. I want to show them together in a single html row..Like this

```
Kevin | IX | 5343634,3565656
Melvin | X | 54534,3778,54434
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach: collect the results in an associative array first, indexed by `name` *as they seem to be unique), then do whatever you want with those results. For example:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $name = $row['name'];
  $results[$name]['class'] = $row['class'];
  $results[$name]['phone'][] = $row['phone'];
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($results as $name => $result) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td><td>' . $result['class'] 
          . '</td><td>' . implode(',', $result['phone']) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Another approach: make your query aggregate the phones itself with GROUP BY and [**CONCAT_WS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
  SELECT name, class, CONCAT_WS(',', phone) AS phones
    FROM students
GROUP BY name
```

Then you'll have all the phones for a given name already served to you in comma-separated format.

---

As a sidenote, consider switching to either `mysqli` or `pdo` extensions - instead of `mysql`. That's what [**PHP documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) says about it:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
>   for writing new code as **it will be removed in the future**. Instead,
>   either the `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

That's not as simple as it may sound, but it's definitely worth the efforts, for prepared statements alone.

Comment: Yep, just me being a bit faster. ) Tho sidenotes on differences: first, I'd rather name a variable that stores a collection of items with plural noun (`$results`, not `$result`); second, there is a mismatch of quotation marks both in the question and in your answer.

Comment: I edited the question. The situation is a bit different.

Comment: @nick Updated the answer. As a sidenote, you really should have described the whole situation in your question right from the start. Instead you have simplified it too much for _any_ answer (given on the original version of the question) to be helpful.

Comment: sorry man... I didn't realize  that the problem would be different. Just in case, if I have more rows which has only 1 value, other than name and class, should I do the same thing?..

Comment: @nick Well, I'd follow the rule of thumb - if there's only one value, store it as a primitive (like `['class']` here), if there can be more than one, choose an array.

Answer (score 0):

Following will show one TD with values comma separated.

```
$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

array_push($result, $row['id']);
}



echo "<table><tr><td>". implode(',',$result) ."</td></tr><table>"
```